# Case Sharing Rules

Tags: roles, case-object, criteria-based-sharing

I have a criteria based sharing rule on a Case -> createdbyid = specific userId, share with a specific role. The role just has one user assigned to it, and the user's profile has Read, Create, Edit, Delete permissions on Case.There are no permission sets assigned to this user. I ran a query to find a list of cases that fit the criteria, but when I log in as the user and search by the case subject, I don't get any results.

Comment: How long between the creation of the case and your search? It can take a bit of time for the indexing for global search to be rebuilt such that new records are picked up, but if there's not much data in the org, that ought not to be an issue really. Have you checked the `Case__share` table as admin to see whether the relevant record for granting access to the role exists in there?

Comment: @barrick I ran the following query: SELECT Id,CaseAccessLevel, UserOrGroup.Name,  from CaseShare where CaseId='xx', and got all for the owner, but there are three more rows for Groups that I don't have access to (as system admin??). Also, they do show in list views, but I can't view them.

Comment: screenshots would help